# delete from many to many field but not from related model

Tags: python, django

Here is my code in django,

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    writer = models.ForeignKey(Email, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    replied_to = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name='replied')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Comment'
```

when I add an instance of comment to replied_to, It adds to parent but replied instance keeps a pointer to related object in its replied_to field.
Is there a way to remove pointer to related Comment without removing reply instace from parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `.remove(..)` method here:

```
mycomment.replied_to.remove(othercomment)
```

This will *not* remove `othercomment` from the database, but it will no longer be part of the `replied_to` in the `ManyToManyField`.

Note that by default `ManyToManyField` relations to `self` are *symmetrical*. That means that if one comment is in the `replied_to` of another comment, then the other comment's `replied_to` also contains the first comment. You can set the [**`symmetrical=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) to `False` to make it *assymetrical*:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    writer = models.ForeignKey(Email, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    replied_to = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False, related_name='replied')
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Comment'
```

Comment: It works but not for hierarchical replied_to. when I want to add a reply to replied comment, It still keeps point to its parent.

Comment: @mdzm: well what is the relation to its parent if it is not `replied_to`?

Comment: If It wasn't replied_to, It's acting like a new comment.

Comment: @mdzm: then I guess you are talking about the relation being symmetrical. What if you specify, as written in the answer `symmetrical=False`? (note that this might have some effects on relations already made).